# How to match multiple characters 'n' times using Python RE module?

Tags: python, regex

I have a sequence: x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x
I want to match 'x-' n times following by x. The x is a number.
How can I do this?
I know that {n} matches the preceding RE n times but the following RE does not work:

```
pattern = \d-{n}\d
```

It is probably trying to match the - n times instead.
I am using python 3.3

[EDIT] One method is using a forloop to concat but I do not want to do this. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that {n} matches the preceding RE n times but the following RE does not work:
>
> ```
> pattern = \d-{n}\d
> ```

Right, because the preceding expression here is `-`.

If you want `\d-` to be the preceding expression, you have to make it a group. This is explained in the [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping), and most other tutorials on regexps:

```
pattern = r'(\d-){n}\d'
```

By default, groups are *capturing*—meaning each one can be referenced in a back reference. Which is usually fine, but if you want to reference *some* groups and not others, read about non-capturing groups a few sections down. Basically:

```
pattern = r'(?:\d-){n}\d'
```

Comment: Thank you for the most informative answer! And you implicitly answered a second question I had.

Answer (score 1):

Put `\d-` in a non-capturing group:

```
>>> re.match(r'(?:\d-){5}\d', '1-2-3-4-5-6')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002BD0C60>
```